# Trigger Custom field

Tags: trigger, custom-field, event

I'm very new with salesforce and with everything related to Apex triger.

I have a little problem and I guess the solution is not complicated but ...

So, When I create a new event, it's always liked to a Contact. The contact name is visible in the "Name" (WhoId).
Because I need to have some information shown in my event (Like mobile number to allow sendig SmS automatically), I need to populate a lookup field I have created (Now It's possible to create a lookup un event)

So, Basically, I need that right after a new event is created, the content of the "WhoID" duplicate to my custom lookup field " lookup_contact__c "

If i'm able to do that, it will work well.

But i'm also curious about something. If, I want to directly populate a custom field in event (Mobile_phone__c for exemple) from the related contact Mobilephone, is it possible ?

Thx a lot for your help. If it's possible, you will save my life (A least, a lot of time)

Comment: Custom lookup fields on OOB Sobject `Event` are not possible

Comment: Yes it's possible. It's new feature in Salesforce. (but we have to ask to enable it)

Comment: I stand corrected .. thanks - see https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrPdAAK Spring 15 Open Beta

Comment: to get best support on this community; members appreciate if the poster has tried out some code and then illustrated where one is getting stuck. There are lots of resources on how to write triggers - just search and dive on in!  You can use the Developer Console to compose and debug the code

Comment: Hum.I just realised 2 things.   My sandbox didn't copy any customisation made in my Salesforce.  And .. The possibility to create custom lookup is not availlable here ...

Comment: Thx for your advise. Actually I did some research and try but nothing work.  Now I have an Idea why. (my custom fields were not duplicate in the Sandbox so ... it count not work for sure)

Comment: yes, when you ask SFDC to enable a feature, you have to specify all orgs (prod and sandbox). Alternatively, if enabled in PROD, you can refresh your sandbox and the pilot beta feature should get 'transferred' to the newly refreshed sandbox